# showHideAutoRenew is not defined?

Tags: upgrade, contribution-page, templates

Got this in the latest CiviCRM  5.69.2, Drupal 10.2.2.  while testing an after-upgrade Contribution pages at */civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1*

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showHideAutoRenew is not defined
toggleRecur https://www.tld.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1:1991
<anonymous> https://www.tld.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1:2041
jQuery 4
    i
    fireWith
    ready
    J
```

Searching further, there is this piece of code in the **MainMembershipBlock.tpl**

> grep -ir "showHideAutoRenew"
>
> ../drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/MainMembershipBlock.tpl:
> showHideAutoRenew( null );
>
> ../drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/MainMembershipBlock.tpl:
> function showHideAutoRenew( memTypeId )
>
> ../drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl:
> showHideAutoRenew(null);
>
> ../drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php:
> 'onclick' => "return showHideAutoRenew(CRM.$(this).data('membershipTypeId'));"

What the heck?

Comment: Can you try this PR? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29033

Comment: Thanks, it looks working, there is an "element.click();" in my version of the template, which is not on the PR though

Comment: There was an earlier PR too: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29016